# Get number of members in linkedin group?

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

I am working on a wordpress website where I need to get the number of members in a particular linkedin group.

The person viewing the website will likely not be logged into linkedin, or ever have a profile.

This is simply for a `Check out our linked in group and join 12345 other members!` type thing.

Is there a simple way to get the number of members in a linkedin group?

This can be PHP using a rest API, a Javascript API, or whatever works as long as it can work with wordpress.

Comment: Good place to start: http://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would pull the group membership totals from the LinkedIn API via the [Groups API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api).

Unfortunately, in order to comply with the [API platform guidelines](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-platform-guidelines), you can only retrieve and show the membership totals of a group to the user if the user has authenticated your application against the API via [OAuth](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

Once you have authenticated the user, you can retrieve the information from the Groups API via a call along the lines of:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/XXXX:(id,name,site-group-url,num-members)
```

Where XXXX is the group ID.

Comment: At the bottom of `Group Output Fields` there is `num-members` which is the number of members in the group. however it seems that you need to be logged in and authorized as a user to access the groups API?

Comment: I stand corrected. Yes, you need to be authorized with the LinkedIn API to access the data. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.linkedin.com/2011/11/10/groups-analytics/

Can this information be useful for you?